# How to filter the results of a hashMap to pick up all Keys starting with a certain letter Groovy

Tags: mysql, groovy, linkedhashmap

I have created a LinkedHashMap, which produces a list of statuses in groovy.
These are the results of a mysql query. I want to filter the results of my map to use key entries (statusName) in the map which start with the letter "O". However I am struggling to find how to do this with a map.

My code is as follows:

```
db.eachRow(reportQuery, [date]) {
      cache.put(it.statusName, it.statusTickets)
    }
    cache.each{statusName, statusTickets ->
      reportMetricsWithValues[statusName] = statusTickets
      table.addData([metric:statusName, value: statusTickets])
    }
```

This is the part of my code where I need to add this filter. The code is adding the key value metrics to a database table.

Answer (score 1):

To filter, you would use `findAll`.  Pass it the map element by element and check, if the key of the element starts with the letter `O`;  Something along the lines of:

```
groovy:000> [zomg: 1, omg: 2].findAll{ it.key.startsWith('o' ) }
===> [omg:2]
```

If you also need the "others", then `groupBy` (same syntax like above) could prove useful.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, adjusting it to what I have above. But it seems to have diregarded it.                                           db.eachRow(reportQuery2, [nocDate]) {
      cache.findAll{it.key.startsWith('O')}
      cache.put(it.statusName, it.statusTickets)
    }

Comment: if you have furhter informations, please edit the question.  it is utterly unreadable in a comment, and quite honest i don't understand, what your ulitmate goal here is.  it eve looks you could as well just `select statusName, statusTicket where statusName like 'O%' order by date'`.